# How to get rid of guilty, sad feeling after resigning and taking back resignation 3 days later?

Tags: salary, resignation, germany

I resigned from my company a week back as I got an opportunity from a company in Munich, Germany without doing much research about Munich and the Company where I am applying.

But two days later I talked to many friends in Germany and came to know that Germany has 42% tax. And considering my income, Munich is very expensive and more than half of my salary would go in housing. Food and all miscellaneous things are very costly too. I wouldn't have much money left compared to what I would have saved in India. Also the company has lots of bad reviews regarding late unpaid hours, no increment, hire and fire. I after some days took back my resignation.

But I don't know why I started feeling very sad and guilty about it overall as if I broke trust and all. I should have thought before resigning. I feel I can't resign within next 1 year as it looks morally wrong, my plans failed for job search. Overall this has made me sad and depressed. Any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question a week ago? https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/122075/how-to-get-rid-of-guilty-sad-feeling-after-resigning-and-taking-back-resignatio

Comment: Didn't get answer properly at that time.

Comment: I'm sorry you didn't get the answer you wanted last time, but I don't think we can resolve your emotional situation here; these kind of situations don't have a "do this and you'll be fine"-kind of answer, and advice would be highly dependent on your personality/specific issues that we don't know. I think you would be better of talking to family, friends, and/or a professional.

Comment: I seriously don't understand why are people downvoting it? It's a complex problems I asked. Instead of guiding, down voting is bad.

Comment: I downvoted your question because it's a re-post of a previously posted question without any changes. I recognize that your problem is real, but re-posting the exact same question after it was removed by the community is not very useful. If you disagree with the closing/voting then the correct procedure is either to edit he question to make it better, or convince people that it *is* on-topic in the comments and/or meta discussion.

Comment: @martin it's deleted and I can't see it. It's better for me to repost obviously. Hope you understand the situation. Else stack overflow is a kinda bullying. I had no other option.

Comment: You should be able to see your own deleted content. If you can't then you probably posted it with a different account.

Comment: I don't think you need to be too concerned about your guilt, more so your continued employment. It's likely your company will be looking to replace you soon.

Comment: Look at the positing things: Munich is a great city with excellent architecture, parks, culture, museums, super active nightlife, and, yes, great Bavarian beer. And look at the numbers correctly: If you make 100,000 Euro/year and are in class I (single), your overall income tax rate should be around 32%. 42% is the marginal rate at the top end.

Comment: @Hilmar I wish it was true. 42% is compulsory tax for single with pay above 54,000 euro. Please Google first before commenting here, it will save your and my time too.

Comment: @Anonymous: I understand that. You pay 42% of the amount ABOVE of 54000 Euro, not the entire amount. If you are making 100000 Euro, your tax would be around 32000 Euro, not 42000 Euro. It's the difference between the marginal tax rate and the average tax rate. See for example https://www.brutto-netto-rechner.info/gehalt/gross_net_calculator_germany.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get past the idea that it's "not moral" or "a breach of trust" to resign. Employment is an agreement between you and your employer for mutual benefit. It's perfectly moral to end or renegotiate it if it stops being as beneficial as you hoped. The only way it becomes a moral or trust issue is *if you made promises in bad faith in return for being taken back*.

Yes, you should have done more research before resigning, and in the eyes of your company you probably appear foolish and impulsive. But this can be repaired. Prove you have learnt by making sure your future decisions are clearly thought out. If you made any promises when taken back, stick to them. Your employer had the option of taking you back, or holding you to your decision, and they clearly felt the former was of more benefit to them. They wouldn't have done that if they saw you as immoral or untrustworthy.

Comment: Thanks. Good answer unlike other people who love to waste their time bullying OP instead of answering politely. I wish the mentality would change for good.

Comment: I feel bad because I could apply for companies if I had thought before resigning. Now I will stay in current company for a year maybe. When would you resign again if you were in my position, in next 1 year as it's not moral to again resign within next 9,10 months?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You can legally resign whenever you want. When you do, you will burn bridges with your current company forever, but that's pretty inevitable anyway. The right time to do it is "when you have a guaranteed alternative job which you are absolutely sure is right for you".

Answer (score 0):

This has been depressing you for 2 weeks now which is bad for your mental state long term. You do need to resolve it.

Work hard and professionally, if the problem persists seek medical advice. Or perhaps if you're religious seek some counselling from that avenue. It's really just a matter of coming to terms with it.

Comment: What would you recommend? Professional help is the last rescue for me. I want to get rid of the feeling without professional help. Because I had antidepressant in past and it has massive side effects. What would you do if you were in my situation? Would you feel a bit sad? When would you resign again if you were in my position, in next 1 year as it's not moral to again resign within next 9,10 months?

Comment: I wouldn't have let it go on this long, I'd have bought my colleagues lunch or something as an apology and that would  be the end of it. I find that doing something concrete for others makes me feel better about a mistake. Unsure if that would work for you.

Comment: I feel bad because I could apply for companies if I had thought before resigning. Now I will stay in current company for a year maybe. When would you resign again if you were in my position, in next 1 year as it's not moral to again resign within next 9,10 months?

Comment: it's not something that would worry me.

Comment: You know very well that if you switch your job, you get better pay. :)

Comment: @Anonymous Professional help should never be the last resort. These are people who studied for years to be able to understand the human body and mind, and are much better equipped to be able to help you than either you or I or anyone else here. Some medication has side effects - if you tell any decent doctor about those, they'd most likely recommend something else. You can also find therapists that won't / can't prescribe medication.

Comment: @Anonymous , professional help is a GREAT THING.  You came to this site to seek help.  You can and should go to a religious leader in your community, or a professional therapist of some kind.  It does not mean taking drugs.  You clearly need someone to talk to about the issues.   Good luck!